# Esiste un modo per sapere quando usare le doppie?

Tags: spelling, geminate-consonants

A volte ho molta difficoltà a capire quando alcune parole richiedono o no una lettera doppia. Fortunatamente con strumenti digitali faccio la correzione automatica e riesco spesso ad usarli bene, però se scrivo rischio di sbagliare. In Italiano alcune parole hanno un significato diverso a seconda di quante lettere uguali metti, per esempio "motto", che vuol dire frase (se non vado sbagliato), e "moto", che vuol dire motocicletta.

**Esiste una regola per sapere quando usare lettere doppie?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nella lingua italiana le lettere consonantiche dell'alfabeto italiano in posizione intervocalica possono essere semplici o doppie.

Tutte le consonanti si presentano in almeno una parola come doppie, compresa la “Q” nelle uniche occorrenze di 'soqquadro' e nel meno utilizzato 'beqquadro', e ad esclusione della “H”, che ha valore prettamente diacritico.
Dal punto di vista della rappresentazione fonetica, ogni doppia rappresenta la geminazione del suono standard che solitamente le viene associato.
**Non c’è una regola specifica per sapere quando utilizzare le lettere doppie.**
Infatti le lettere doppie dell’italiano sono un fenomeno complesso, perché non sono l’esito di un unico percorso evolutivo, ma il risultato di diverse trasformazioni ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/lettere-doppie_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)).

Già già in greco e in latino esistevano parole con lettere doppie.
Le parole che derivano dal greco tendono a conservare le lettere doppie (talassocrazia, da thalassa «mare» + krátos «potere»).
In genere anche le parole latine che contenevano lettere doppie le hanno mantenute in italiano: si pensi a parole come ancilla > ancella, căballus > cavallo, commercĭum > commercio, stella > stella.
Nel passaggio dal latino all’italiano vengono introdotte lettere doppie estranee al latino in seguito a diversi fenomeni:

- **geminazione della consonante che segue la vocale tonica nelle parole sdrucciole**, come nel caso di femĭna(m) > femmina o căthĕdra(m) > cattedra.
- **assimilazione consonantica**, cioè la trasformazione della prima consonante nella seconda. Le parole greche e latine contenenti il nesso -x- (cioè la consonante doppia -cs-) come saxum > sasso, come ălexănder > Alessandro. L’assimilazione ha trasformato, inoltre, anche altri nessi ostici come

  - **-ps-** (scrīpsi > scrissi),
  - **-ct-** (noctem > notte),
  - **-pt-** (aptum > atto, da cui attore, attitudine, ecc.),
  - **-mn-** (cŏlumna > colonna)

  e ha agito nell’evoluzione di parole con suffisso diminutivo come

  - fēnūc(ū)lum > finocchio,
  - aurĭc(ŭ)la > orecchia,
  - vĕt(ŭ)lŭm > *vĕtlŭ (= veclu) > vecchio.
    In questi casi, a essere assimilato è il nesso **-cl-** che si trasforma in velare rafforzata.

  Un particolare tipo di assimilazione consonantica, simile a un raddoppiamento fonosintattico regressivo, riguarda, invece, le parole formate con prefissi latini, quali:

  - **ad-** e **sub-** (advĕntŭm > avvento, sub + portāre > supportare).
  - Inducono, poi, al raddoppiamento della consonante iniziale della parola a cui sono uniti anche altri prefissi come, per es., **ra-** (rappresentare), **so-** (socchiudere), **contra-** (contrapporre).
    Tuttavia, per secoli, questi hanno dato esiti oscillanti tra scempie e doppie: la forma contradire (in luogo di contraddire), per es., ancora ai primi del Novecento era indicata come la più comune nel manuale di ortografia di Malagoli (1912).
- **L’assimilazione progressiva** si verifica, invece, coi prefissi **in-** e **con-** seguiti da nasale o liquida in casi come immeritevole (in + meritevole), irresponsabile (in + responsabile), illegale (in + legale), correlativo (con + relativo).
  Il fenomeno dell’assimilazione progressiva è anche un esito tipico dei dialetti dell’Italia centro-meridionale in parole come mŭndum > monno, fŭndum > fonno.

Detto questo, **esistono delle regole per non sbagliare nello scrivere parole con lettere doppie** (*Manuale di scrittura non creativa*, Rizzoli):

> - **b** non si scrive **mai doppia** davanti al suffisso – ile: mobile, visibile;
> - **g** non si scrive **mai doppia** davanti a – ione: ragione;
> - **z** non si scrive **mai doppia**:
>
>   - nei nomi terminanti in **– ione**: eccezione, lezione;
>   - nei nomi terminanti in **– zia**, **– zie**, **– zio** (malizia, polizia, giudizio, ospizio ecc.) e nei loro derivati (poliziesco, giudiziario ecc.). 
>       Ci sono però **alcune eccezioni** a questa regola generale : si scrivono con zz le parole pazzia, razzia, razziale, carrozziere, tappezziere, corazziere, mazziere;
> - **z** si scrive **sempre doppia** nelle parole composte con i suffissi: – **ozzo**, **– uzzo**, **– izzare**, e nei loro derivati: predicozzo, peluzzo, organizzare, organizzatore;
> - **la consonante iniziale di una parola raddoppia quando si unisce**:
>
>   - alle congiunzioni **e, né, se, o** (ebbene, neppure, seppure, ovvero);
>   - alle preposizioni **a/ad, da, fra, su** (alla, addizionare, dapprima, frapporre, suddetto)
>   - agli avverbi **là, più, sì, così** (laggiù, piuttosto, siffatto, cosiddetto)
>   - ai prefissi **sopra, sovra, contra** (soprattutto, sopravvivere, sovrabbondante, soprannumero, sopralluogo, contraddire, contraccolpo)
>   - quando la prima parola è il prefisso **ra-** (raddrizzare, raccogliere, rammendare).
>       Non si ha il raddoppiamento:
>   - se la seconda parola che forma il composto inizia con **s impura** (cioè seguita da consonante): soprascritto, sovrastruttura, contrastante;
>   - dopo i prefissi **contro-, pre-, tra-, sotto-, intra-** (controbattere, controluce, prevedere, precedere, trapiantare, sottoporre, sottobosco, intravedere, intramuscolare).

Forse sono stata un po' prolissa, ma spero di essere stata di aiuto.

Comment: Non so cosa vuole dire "prolissa", ma grazie. Molto esaudiente come risposta :-)

Comment: @chestres significa: dilungarsi troppo nel parlare di qualcosa. Vale anche per lo scritto

Comment: Oggi ho imparato due cose nuove! Grazie

Answer (score 6):

Non ci può essere una regola. Gli esempi di coppie minime sono tanti:

> casa/cassa
>     fata/fatta
>     copia/coppia
>     cola/colla
>     sera/serra

e così via. Nessun correttore automatico che non abbia anche un controllo semantico può segnalare errori in questi casi.

Se pronunciamo *vale* (voce del verbo *valere*) e *valle* (quella che sta fra i monti), la *a* nella prima parola è leggermente più lunga e, naturalmente, il suono di *ll* è “più intenso” di *l* semplice, almeno nella pronuncia standard.

La *z* sorda intervocalica seguita da *i* si pronuncia sempre geminata (termine più preciso di “doppia”), ma normalmente si scrive semplice: *azione*. Se però la *z* è doppia in una parola, lo è anche nelle parole derivate: *mazza* e *mazziere*; invece da *dazio* viene *daziere*, da *Lazio* viene *laziale*. Le *z* in queste sei parole si pronunciano allo stesso modo, cioè geminate.

Un problema analogo per chi impara l'italiano riguarda l'accento tonico: non c'è alcuna regola per decidere su quale sillaba cade. Un esempio classico è *capitano* che può avere l'accento tonico su tre delle quattro sillabe

> càpitano (verbo *capitare*)
>     capitàno (ufficiale dell'esercito)
>     capitanò (verbo *capitanare*)

L'accento si segna solo nell'ultimo caso.

Comment: Grazie per l'ultima specificazioni, non ci avevo pensato!

Answer (score 1):

L'unica soluzione è imparare a distinguere la diversa pronuncia. Il motivo per cui so che *moto* si scrive con una lettera sola e *motto* con due è perché se le dico a voce alta, la prima la pronuncio ['mɔto] e la seconda ['mɔt:o].

Se la tua lingua madre è una lingua che non ha le consonanti doppie (come molte lingue europee e una buona percentuale delle lingue regionali italiane) questo può richiedere un po' di sforzo all'inizio, ma di fatto i grafemi t e tt sono due lettere distinte, che corrispondono a suoni distinti. Da questo punto di vista la tua domanda è un po' come chiedere come ricordarsi di scrivere *moto* piuttosto che *modo*.

Una buona risorsa per consultare varie pronunce italiane di madrelingua (ma attenzione: le pronunce variano su base regionale, e le lettere doppie sono di solito pronunciate con maggiore intensità al centro-sud che al nord) è [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/it/).

Comment: beh, esiste qualche eccezione, ad esempio "_agglomerato_"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Oops giusto. Facciamo che elimino quel paragrafo, tanto non aggiungeva niente di particolarmente util

Comment: Pronuncie è senza i

Comment: @chestres Il dizionario Treccani dà effettivamente *pronunce* come plurale. Viceversa dà come corretto sia *province* (norma moderna) sia *provincie*.

Comment: Ugh, questo mi insegna a non scrivere risposte a mezzanotte passata. La prossima volta sentitevi liberi di correggere direttamente :)

Comment: @Denis Nardin Bellissimo il sito Forvo, non lo conoscevo, Grazie!